# attenuate "front end developer"

Tags: synonyms

I think my question would fit better in stackoverflow, but as it isn't a technical question I'm posting it here.

For a CV-type document I need to "headline" my role in fixing an issue.

I did some modification on the front end of an software tool, but I think the term `front end developer` is a bit to "high" as it already existed and I just edited minor things. Is there a good way/word to describe my having done this?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I’d turn it into a statement, rather than a noun. “Assisted in front end development”, eg.

Comment: @DanBron thx, but this sounds like I assisted someone else (with was not the case). Well I modified someone else work true, but I was not his assistant put it that way

Comment: How about: bug fixer

Comment: How about "Did maintenance work on the front end". This would cover user environment improvements and meeting changing requirements as well as fixing bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about front end editor? Tweaker? Modifier? "made front end alterations"
Also, since you're going to "headline" the role, I assume you'll also have space to give a description of what you did. If you feel there isn't a good buzz phrase or title for what you did, you can always stick with "front end developer" and then use the description to clarify.